# Context free grammar

Tags: context-free-grammar

For the following non regular language, I want the Context Free Grammar and the rightmost derivation for the string 011000.

L={0^m 1^n 0^(m+n)| m,n >=0}

For the CFG I have done this:
S --> 0S0 | A
A --> 10A | E
Is it right?

For the rightmost derivation for the string 011000 im having some dificulties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CFG for this language is as follows

```
S->0S0|A
A->1A0|^
```

Your CFG will accept this string 010100 which is wrong. 
Now you might get your right-most derivation.

Comment: What do you mean by ^?

Comment: ^ means E (null character)

Comment: Ok thank you. But still i dont know how to do the derivation because i am really starting with all this. Can you help me?

Comment: S->0S0->0A0->01A00->011A000->011^000->011000